# C++ Class template deduction (P0091R0) for function arguments

Tags: c++, c++17

In C++17 we can do somthing like

```
std::pair p = {1,3}; // compiler deduces template parameters to pair<int,int>
```

From the documentation at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_deduction) I understand that the following will NOT work:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
void bar(std::pair<T1,T2>)
{}
void foo()
{
   bar({1,3}); // No deduction of pair template arguments
}
```

Can anyone confirm this and give some insight, why this won't work? Technically this should work, right? Has there been any discussion to make this work, or is it kind of an oversight?

Comment: Think about it - we need to know which constructor to use with the braces, but to know which one to use we must know the type, but we don't know the type until we find the constructor (the constructors can be different for every type substitution thanks to explicit specialization)

Comment: @milleniumbug That argument would apply just as much to the normal declaration case - specializations are not considered.

Comment: @Barry Except that in the function template case you have multiple possible targets and the template parameter list can be arbitrarily complicated.

Comment: @T.C. i don't understand that. Why would that prevent it? It would raise the ambiguity bar, but that would be the choice of the user. It could be an opt-in feature that is enabled by a keyword, perhaps.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Link doesn't work. It doesn't seem particularly useful with all the ambiguities left and right, and I'd imagine is more complex to specify since instead of deducing against `pair<T1, T2>` always, you have to provide for deducing against `pair<T, T>` or `pair<T, remove_cv_t<T>>` or whatnot too.

Comment: @T.C. sorry it was a link to my mailbox.  Repeated with correct link: I have "proposed" this on std-proposals a while ago: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!msg/std-proposals/uEVqlnf7bh0/pDoEcXuSFQAJ . if you want, you can comment there and express your sympathy or concerns.

Comment: @T.C. good point, that issue didn't come to my mind.

Answer (score 11):

The reference is correct. Template argument deduction for class templates as currently adopted applies *solely* to declarations (and explicit type conversions - which are defined in terms of declarations), in [dcl.type.class.deduct]:

> If a placeholder for a deduced class type appears as a *decl-specifier* in the *decl-specifier-seq* of a *simple-declaration*, the *init-declarator* of that declaration shall be of the form
>
> *declarator-id* *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub> *initializer*
>
> The placeholder is replaced by the return type of the function selected by overload resolution for class template deduction (13.3.1.8). If the *init-declarator-list* contains more than one *init-declarator*, the type that
>   replaces the placeholder shall be the same in each deduction. *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> template<class T> struct container {
>     container(T t) {}
>     template<class Iter> container(Iter beg, Iter end);
> };
>
> template<class Iter>
> container(Iter b, Iter e) -> container<typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type>;
>
> std::vector<double> v = { /* ... */};
> container c(7);                          // OK, deduces int for T
> auto d = container(v.begin(), v.end());  // OK, deduces double for T
> container e{5, 6};                       // error, int is not an iterator
> ```
>
> *—end example ]*

There was nothing in the proposal or the adopted wording about deducing a class template specialization from a *braced-init-list*.